# Will add-ons for EE2 work in EE3?

Tags: add-on, addons

Searching in 3rd party add-ons, there do not seem to be many that work with Expression Engine 3. In fact, there are almost none that list as compatible. Can I use add-ons listed as compatible with EE 2 in EE 3?

Should I not use EE 3 and instead use EE 2 if I need add-ons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EE2 add-on's are NOT compatible with EE3. Add-on authors are making the transition, but depending on the complexity of the add-on and the availability of the developer, some will take time.

You can view a list of the current add-ons that are EE3 ready here... https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/filter?&f=ee3

And here is a semi-comprehensive list of other add-ons intentions...
https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-3-add-on-developer-update-status

Comment: Thank you, so is it better to stick with ee2 for now then?

Comment: Completely depends on your add-on needs. I have two EE3 sites in the works right now.